# Xcode 5 - Launch Images in Asset catalog won't show up

Tags: xcode, image, assets, launch, sprite-kit

I have a problem with my LaunchImages. When I create a new Project with the SpriteKit template and immediately add my two launch images, everything works fine. Now I change the Device Orientation (General->Deployment Info) to Landscape-Left and Landscape-Right (unselect "Portrait). I run the simulator again and the images won't show up. (even if I allow "Portrait"-Orientation again)
Does somebody know, whats this about?

A second Question: 
When I tried to use an asset catalog with a SKSpriteNode object, the image doesn't show up as well. Instead the Node was a dark green rectangle. If I try to assign the same image to a UIImageView everything works fine...

Comment: I fiddled with asset catalogs for a while, specifically for launch images. Eventually I gave up and did it the old way without asset catalogs. Something tells me they are inherently broken. I would get errors if I made the image sizes according to the asset catalog but the compiler complained. When I used the pre-catalog resolutions I couldn't add them to the asset catalog in the first place. From what I heard Sprite Kit doesn't even support asset catalogs (yet). I'll try again in Xcode 5.1 ...

Answer (score 2):

Verify you don't have the launch image name specified on your ...Info.plist file
for me it was the problem preventing default image to be displayed on iOS 6 and below while it was working for iOS 7

Comment: Yeah, thank you. That did it for me. Just leaves me with the question, why Xcode does not do this automatically, if you migrate to Image Assets...iOS 7 and Xcode 5 just keep me wondering (kindly spoken)...

Comment: I also wonder, I spend nearly 2 hours to figure out how to solve this yesterday (for one of my own application)